# Is it possible to apply styling to particular words in radio-group/checkbox options?

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a requirement for applying **bolding** to particular words in a radio-group option.  Is this possible with LWC?

eg.

> There **is a** problem
>
> There is **no** problem

Unfortunately we cannot reword the options to make them clearer as they legislated to be worded a particular way :(

I tried adding <b> in to the label but just ended up with that displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a custom library function and use [lwc:dom="manual"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library) in order to create a custom renderer to support this type of functionality. There's simply no real way to dynamically create DOM components in LWC, or provide unescaped HTML (as aura:unescapedHtml), so you'd be left with writing a static resource that contains logic to render a custom DOM. It's not impossible, but it's going to be a lot more work than you'd probably like to invest in.

Comment: Thanks - figured that was the case. Told them about a week to implement it if they really wanted it.  They decided capitalisation would have to do, but had to put the question out there to make sure I was not missing a hidden trick to do so.